# sort a defaultdict(list) by highest item number

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dictionary

I have the following code that I have created from running some analysis and I have put the results in a defaultdict(list). Afterwards I put the results into a csv file. Id like to sort the values that Im returning so that the more important items go to the top.

I want to sort my defaultdict(list) by **"Check1"** from greatest to least.

How would I sort the values so that for each key(address) the dictionary with the highest **"Check1"** comes first?

```
defaultdict(list,
                     {'Address_1': [{'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_1',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 8,
                 'Check2' : 1},
              {'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_2',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 20,
                 'Check2' : 1},
              {'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_3',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 27,
                 'Check2' : 1}],
              'Address_2': [{'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_1',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 30,
                 'Check2' : 1},
              {'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_2',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 38,
                 'Check2' : 1},
              {'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_3',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 12,
                 'Check2' : 1}]})
```

Result would look like this:

```
defaultdict(list,          {'Address_1': [{'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_1',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 27,
                 'Check2' : 1},
              {'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_2',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 20,
                 'Check2' : 1},
              {'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_3',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 8,
                 'Check2' : 1}],
              'Address_2': [{'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_1',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 38,
                 'Check2' : 1},
              {'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_2',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 30,
                 'Check2' : 1},
              {'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_3',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc',
                'Check1' : 12,
                 'Check2' : 1}]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your expected outcome by using `sorted` function + dict comprehension.

Specifically, we can iterate over the key-value pairs of the defaultdict dictionary (where each value is a list of dictionaries) and sort each value, i.e. list of dictionaries, by the `'Check1'` keys of each dictionary in each list. `sorted` sorts in ascending order by default, but since we want to sort in descending order, we add the `-` sign to sort in the correct order.

```
out = {k: sorted(lst, key=lambda x: -x.get('Check1')) for k, lst in your_defaultdict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'Address_1': [{'Name': 'name',
   'Address_match': 'address_match_3',
   'ID': 'id',
   'Type': 'abc',
   'Check1': 27,
   'Check2': 1},
  {'Name': 'name',
   'Address_match': 'address_match_2',
   'ID': 'id',
   'Type': 'abc',
   'Check1': 20,
   'Check2': 1},
  {'Name': 'name',
   'Address_match': 'address_match_1',
   'ID': 'id',
   'Type': 'abc',
   'Check1': 8,
   'Check2': 1}],
 'Address_2': [{'Name': 'name',
   'Address_match': 'address_match_2',
   'ID': 'id',
   'Type': 'abc',
   'Check1': 38,
   'Check2': 1},
  {'Name': 'name',
   'Address_match': 'address_match_1',
   'ID': 'id',
   'Type': 'abc',
   'Check1': 30,
   'Check2': 1},
  {'Name': 'name',
   'Address_match': 'address_match_3',
   'ID': 'id',
   'Type': 'abc',
   'Check1': 12,
   'Check2': 1}]}
```

Comment: This answers rebuilds a new dict containing new lists, which seems a bit overkill for the op; sorting the lists in place as suggested in @Marat's answer is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's the problem is, pretty straightforward:

```
for key, values in dictionary.items():
    values.sort(key=lambda value: value['Check1'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: I suggest iterating on `dictionary.values()` instead, since you're not doing anything with the keys.